# eWay: Undefined variable: CRM16923 AnUnreliableMethodHasBeenUserToDeterminePaymentProcessorFromContributionPage

Tags: wordpress, recurring-contributions, eway

> Undefined variable:
>   CRM16923AnUnreliableMethodHasBeenUserToDeterminePaymentProcessorFromContributionPage
>   in
>   .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
>   on line 2459
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in
>   ..../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php
>   on line 221

I am using Eway (Recurring) Payment Processor : https://github.com/fuzionnz/com.chrischinchilla.ewayrecurring

CiviCRM version: 5.13.4
Wordpress version: 5.2.2

The problem occurs when I view a Contribution and then click on Email Invoice, it gives the above error.
[image]

Comment: Note that this extension has been acknowledged by its author to be abandoned and has been de-listed from in-app installation in CiviCRM: https://github.com/ChrisChinchilla/CiviCRM-eWay-recurring-payment-processor/issues/59 Another eWay processor is currently in the process of being made ready for in-app installation approval (and can be installed manually in the meantime): https://civicrm.org/extensions/eway-recurring-payment-processor-agileware

Comment: @TwoMice I have updated it to the new extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/eway-recurring-payment-processor-agileware but I still get the same error

Comment: I have updated the above to the latest versions 5.26.0 with current agileware extension but still it gives the above error ,only when I commemnt line 2800 under CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php i.e. 
if ($paymentProcessorID) {
       // $intentionalEnotice = $CRM16923AnUnreliableMethodHasBeenUserToDeterminePaymentProcessorFromContributionPage;
      } 
and the error disappears, is this correct ?